# Object match error when running a Python script from command line Maya

Tags: python, batch-file, executable, maya

I have this script in Python which I'm running into a maya file from a command line:

```
import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize("Python")
import maya.cmds as cmds
from maya import cmds
import maya.mel as mel
import glob


def importFile(i):
    cmds.file(i, i=True, groupReference=True, groupName="myobj")


def materialFile():
    if cmds.objExists('Panel*'):
        cmds.select("Panel*", replace=True)
        myMaterial = "BlueGlass"
        cmds.sets( e=True, forceElement= myMaterial + 'SG' ) 

    if cmds.objExists('Body*'):
        cmds.select("Body*", replace=True)
        myMaterial3 = "Silver"
        cmds.sets( e=True, forceElement= myMaterial3 + 'SG' )
```

But I get this error when I try to run the batch file:

```
File "/Users/../Scripts/MayaVectorScript.py", line 23, in materialFile
        cmds.sets( e=True, forceElement= myMaterial + 'SG' ) 
TypeError: No object matches name: BlueGlassSG
```

In the Hypershade, the shader BlueGlass is connected to a shader group (SG) with the same name BlueglassSG and the script works from the UI inside maya.

Do I need to load a plugin or something in the script to make it run in the batch file?

Comment: the shader group is called "BlueglassSG", you are looking for "BlueGlassSG", is that clear?

Comment: @AriGold Well I guess I need to find it in python. But, how?

Comment: myMaterial = "BlueGlass" to  myMaterial = "Blueglass" ? I think that's what Ari was talking about.

Comment: @Achayan Should I write something like: `myShadingGroup= BlueglassSG` bellow `myMaterial = "BlueGlass"` ??

Comment: Are you able to upload the scene somewhere?

Comment: @GreenCell https://www.dropbox.com/s/h3toyxrl94k2fyl/New_Project.zip?dl=0 the file is actually a little bit more complex. the scripts are in the script folder

Comment: In the scene you sent me, BlueGlass does NOT exist in the scene! :)
I was able to run PythonScript.py in your scene without any errors. But anyways it's clear that it can't detect BlueGlass in your scene. If you're importing it from another file then it's possible it got renamed during import.

Comment: @GreenCell Well, yes certainly that was an original script so i changed BlueGlass for BlueDiamond and Panel for Gem*. Were you able to run it from the batch file?

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce some of the potential for error by using listConnections to get the shading groups instead of using names. Names usually works but it's not guaranteed.  This will still not work if you type the material name incorrectly, but it should make it clearer where you've gotten messed up:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def get_sg(shader):
    sgs =  cmds.ls(cmds.listHistory(shader, f=True) or [''], type='shadingEngine') or [None]
    return sgs[0]

def assign(geometry, shader):
    if not geometry:
       cmds.error("No objects to assign")
    sg = get_sg(shader)
    if not sg:
        cmds.error('could not find shader ' + shader)
    cmds.sets(geometry, fe=sg)

assign(cmds.ls('Panel*'), 'BlueGlass')
assign(cmds.ls('Body*'), 'Silver')
```

Comment: Do I need to change the name of `(geometry, shader)` for `(panel, BlueGlass)` ??

Also, can 'blinn1' be replaced by BlueGlass and Silver? As they are the shaders names

Comment: oh ok I understood. Geometry is assigned to Panel* and Body* and shader to BlueGlass and Silver. But still it doesn't work when I run the script. It completes the script but it doesn't apply materials.

Comment: Does it print an error? It should be hard for it it run run without doing something -- the fail cases should generate error messages

Comment: @throdox it prints the error 'no objects to assign'. I tried different ways like if objExist: or moving the  ssign(cmds.ls('Panel*'), 'BlueGlass under 
def assign(geometry, shader):

Comment: that error would mean cmds.ls('Panel*') is returning nothing.  Is the geometry present and named as you expect?

Comment: the file/files get imported when the script is running. So the process is: import, apply materials, render, delete and continue with the next file

Comment: @theodoxl Well, yes it  was from another script but i changed BlueGlass for BlueDiamond and Panel for Gem*. And it's basically the same. The BlueDiamond shading group is BLueDiamondSG

Comment: Depending on how you import the objects you may get prefixes or namespaces.  What about `cmds.ls("*Body", r=True)` ? The `r` will check all namespaces and the * will handle prefixes

Comment: Sorry I was to busy with another project. you mean `assign(cmds.ls("*Body", r=True), 'blinn1')`???

Comment: more or less -- you'd want to see what `cmds.ls("*Body", r=True)` returns, since the error you posted makes it look like the objects are not present in the scene under the exact names you gave

Comment: now it runs without error but still it doesn't apply materials. Also it runs without erros from batch file. I placed in the same line it under `if not sg:` also the same line under `cmds.error('could not find shader ' + shader)`

Comment: see the edit to the code I just made - I forgot to replace a test value with the variable `shader`

Comment: When place the `assign(cmds.ls('*Gem'), 'BlueGlass'` in the same place of the code you wrote, it gives the error "No objects to assign". If I move it with the tab key one space, it runs the script without errors but it doesn't apply any material

Comment: I could make it run properly applying only one color. In order to apply another color, I need to write all the code you posted and change the shader and the geometry. The problem now is, it applies to elements which are already in the scene. But it doesn't recognises the importing obj from the script