# Shading Groups Missing python batch

Tags: python

I have the batch file where I apply materials to imported OBJ files. When I run the python code inside maya it works perfectly. But form the batch file an error appears

`TypeError: No object matches name: BlueDiamondSG`

I got some help from users and other codes to fix it up  but still it doesn't apply the materials. It seems like it doesn't load the hyperspace materials or something like that. 
If I write load `cmds.loadPlugin("hyperShade")` or any hypershade command on the batch file, it says `hypeshade is not supported in batch mode`

so how I suppose to apply materials from my batch file?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  I can't answer your question, but I think you should change some things in it, or it will likely be downvoted and removed. Try to provide significantly more context; what exactly did you try and what went wrong when you tried it? Include minimal code to reproduce your error if applicable.  Good luck, and hope your get your problem figured out! :)

Comment: @ChristopherShroba I posted the code in another question, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624108/object-match-error-when-running-a-python-script-from-command-line-maya?noredirect=1#comment68651882_40624108
I received some help on that post and the result is the same. That makes me think that when maya opens in the background it doesn't load the library where shading groups and materials are placed.